# Passing arguments to function expressions with embedded function

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to understand the argument passing mechanism for function expressions that have functions within them, requiring argument passing. I think I know what is happening, but not sure.

I have the following code fragment:

```
makePassword(password) {
   return function guess(passwordGuess) {
      return (passwordGuess === password);
   }
}

var tryGuess = makePassword("secret");
console.log("Guessing 'nope': " + tryGuess("nope"));
console.log("Guessing 'secret': " + tryGuess("secret"));
```

`tryGuess` gets the function reference of `makePassword("secret")`. I understand that. I'm trying to wrap my head around why `tryGuess("nope")` passes `nope` to the inner function `guess` and not to `makePassword`? I'm think that, in this example, `password` is set before the function reference is passed to `tryGuess`?

If that is so, how would I pass the parameters to `password` and `passwordGuess` in `tryGuess` if I had assigned `tryGuess` like this:

```
var tryGuess = makePassword();
```

There is an assumption about nested functions and parameter passing that I must be missing.

Comment: `tryGuess` will be the return value of `makePassword` which will be `guess`. So calling `tryGuess` will run that inner function, which has access to both `password` and `passwordGuess` due to the closure.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do JavaScript closures work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work)

Comment: if you call makePassword() just like that, password will be undefind, and it will compare any next chack you make with that

Comment: Ok, this makes sense now!!

Answer (score 2):

`makePassword` takes the `password` argument and returns a function that uses that value. `makePassword('secret')` returns a function that effectively is:

```js
function guess(passwordGuess) {
    return (passwordGuess === 'secret');
}
```

And calling `var tryGuess = makePassword("secret");` assigns it to `tryGuess`.

From this point onwards, it's a function like any other function. Calling `tryGuess('nope')` will return false (because `'nope' === 'secret'` is `false`), while calling `tryGuess('secret')` will return `true`.

Comment: Thank you so much! I wish the book I was reading had explained it that way!!

Answer (score 2):

`var tryGuess = makePassword("secret");`

is not returning a reference to the function `makePassword` but it calls the function and assigns `tryGuess` the return value of the function `makePassword` which in this case is the reference to guess function. The value of password is fixed when you ran `makePassword("secret")` as secret